# Play/Pause doesn't work with useEffect and using setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code. Whenever I play the start button, it spasms out. Any help would be appreciated! I'm wanting to, whenever I press the button, a timer for 1 second to count down based on the truthiness of isPlaying.

```
const [onBreak, setOnBreak] = useState(false) 
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const timerFunc = setInterval(() => {
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
    if (!onBreak) {
      if (sessionSec === 0 && sessionMin !== 0) {
        setSessionSec(59);
        setSessionMin(sessionMin - 1);
      } else if (sessionSec !== 0 && sessionMin !== 0) {
        setSessionSec(sessionSec - 1);
      } else if (sessionSec === 0 && sessionMin === 0) {
        setOnBreak(true);
      }
    } else if (onBreak) {
      if (breakSec === 0 && breakMin !== 0) {
        setBreakSec(59);
        setBreakMin(breakMin - 1);
      } else if (breakSec !== 0 && breakMin !== 0) {
        setBreakSec(breakSec - 1);
      } else if (breakSec === 0 && breakMin === 0) {
        setOnBreak(false);
      }
    } else {
      clearInterval(timerFunc);
    }
  }, 100);
}, [isPlaying]);


<button onClick={() => setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)}>{isPlaying ? 'Pause': 'Play'}</button>
```

Comment: Why do you call setIsPlaying inside the useEffect? That will cause the useEffect to run again and again, since it manipulates the isPlaying property you use to trigger the effect.

Answer (score 0):

If `setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)` calls `useEffect()` then only call `setIsPlaying(1isPlaying)` once in the onclick. You also need to change the interval duration to 1000 to wait for one second e.g.

```
const [onBreak, setOnBreak] = useState(false) 
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const timerFunc = setInterval(() => {
    if (!onBreak) {
      if (sessionSec === 0 && sessionMin !== 0) {
        setSessionSec(59);
        setSessionMin(sessionMin - 1);
      } else if (sessionSec !== 0 && sessionMin !== 0) {
        setSessionSec(sessionSec - 1);
      } else if (sessionSec === 0 && sessionMin === 0) {
        setOnBreak(true);
      }
    } else if (onBreak) {
      if (breakSec === 0 && breakMin !== 0) {
        setBreakSec(59);
        setBreakMin(breakMin - 1);
      } else if (breakSec !== 0 && breakMin !== 0) {
        setBreakSec(breakSec - 1);
      } else if (breakSec === 0 && breakMin === 0) {
        setOnBreak(false);
      }
    } else {
      clearInterval(timerFunc);
    }
  }, 1000);
}, [isPlaying]);


<button onClick={() => setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)}>{isPlaying ? 'Pause': 'Play'}</button>
```